# htaccess redirects to blank page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mobile

Recently my wordpress [website](http://www.orbitaltraffic.com.au) was hacked, and mobiles were redirected to an *unsavoury* site. I didn't have any previous knowledge of .htaccess, but I'd read that the culprit would be there. And it was, so I deleted everything in the .htaccess file. But it stopped working entirely, so I found this generic wordpress redirect code. The code is

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It works fine now when viewed from a desktop machine, but whenever it is viewed from a mobile device it redirects to a blank page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to post up a link to the site?

Comment: I did, the word "website" is a link. But, I must tell you that I'm having some Cisco problems, so you won't be able to get access to it. I know it makes it difficult to answer, but I figured maybe someone had heard of this.

Comment: Your WP rule set is missing the rule to prevent loops: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` below `RewriteBase /`. It is important to include it, although it does not solve your actual problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there was probably a specific mobile redirect rule in your old .htaccess file, which has now been erased and/or there is some specific WordPress code that handels the redirect.

Ideally, you would restore your files from a backup. But if you don't have a backup, you'll have to do some sleuthing.

I am not particularly familiar with WordPress, but I suspect you probably installed a WordPress plugin in order to get the mobile-specific functionality or redirect. If that's the case, you should either reinstall it or reach out to the maintainers of that plug in.

Otherwise, you can find a variety of different Apache redirect snippets for redirecting mobile devices - some [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+mobile+redirect+.htaccess&aq=f&oq=wordpress+mobile+redirect+.htaccess&aqs=chrome.0.57j0j62l3j64.8357&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) would probably help you find what you need.

Comment: I agree with Arthur, and suggest that you install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/ to prevent that you get hacked again (you probably left your .htaccess file writable!)